# vba compatability from 2016 to lower version

Tags: vba

I have written the following code to copy and paste data from Excel sheets to Powerpoint slides in Microsoft Excel 2016 version.

However, when I run this code on lower Microsoft Excel version it gives an error message at the mentioned place (second last row of code):-

```
Sub excltoppt()

Dim ppalApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppalPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppalSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppalApp = New PowerPoint.Application

ppalApp.Visible = True
ppalApp.Activate

Set ppalPres = ppalApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.pptx")

ppalPres.Slides(6).Duplicate
Set ppalSlide = ppalPres.Slides(6)

'here it select data from specific excel sheet #6    
Sheets("S06").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("D1:G21").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Copy

'here it paste at the selected specific slide #6
ppalSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

'here it select data from specific excel sheet #6
Sheets("S06").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("D14:H18").Select
    Selection.Copy

'here it paste at the selected specific slide #6 - AND AT THIS PLACE I AM GETTING ERROR MESSAGE
ppalSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

End Sub
```

It copies data from excel, paste it on ppt, again copy it from excel but this time it **doesn't** paste it in ppt.

Comment: What is the error message you get?  and a few observations.. it looks like your pasting twice to the same area, did the first one work and the second not?  The first time you are selecting all shapes, and the second time you aren't.

Comment: Yes JosephC...first time I am selecting all shapes in Sheet 6, copying and paste it in Slide number 6 of presentation. Second time, I am selecting only a table (available in the range of D14:H18), copying and paste it again in Slide number 6.
For the first time it is working perfectly.. however second time it throws an error message (at this step :- ppalSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText)

The error message I am getting is:-
Run-time error '-2147188160 (800482240)':
Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.

Comment: I'm defiantly not an expert when it comes to vba & powerpoint.  I'm guessing problem is one of two things.  1. Shapes.PasteSpecial doesn't like not having just a table to paste, or 2. something from the first paste is locking up the second.  So as a test, what happens when you switch the order of your copy statements?  Which one(s) paste, and does your error follow the "just a table" copy?

Comment: Shorts tests on office 2016 and office 2007 shows the same problem on my side.

Comment: It does work on PowerPoint 2007 if you paste as `ppPasteOLEObject` instead of default or text.

Comment: Thanks Vincent G
But using ppPasteOLEObject doesn't give me freedom to edit the text in PowerPoint. As per standard this data should be pasted as editable table only so that it could also be changed afterwards.

Comment: May I request for a suggestion on my issue that I am facing..... :(